# Вывод двоичных чисел в которых две единицы не стоят рядом

Tags: c++

Задание: требуется подсчитать количество последовательностей длины N ,
состоящих из 0 и 1, в которых никакие две единицы не стоят рядом. Я сделал только вывод общего кол-ва, как мне сделать вывод самих двоичных чисел?
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int countStrings(const int n )
{
    vector<int> a(n), b(n); //Создадим вектор для работы со строками
    // a[i] - Двоичные числа длины i, которые не содержат двух последовательных 1 и заканчиваются 0
    // b[i] - Аналогично a[i], только заканчиваются 1
    a[0] = b[0] = 1; // Базовый случай
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + b[i-1]; // К строке, заканчивающейся 0, мы можем добавить 0 или 1
        b[i] = a[i-1]; // К строке, заканчивающейся 1 мы можем добавить ТОЛЬКО 0
    }
    return a[n-1] + b[n-1];
}

int main()
{ 
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    cout << countStrings(N) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Примерно то же самое. Выводите 0, и далее рекурсивно для длины n-1. Потом - 1 и далее рекурсивно для n-1, начинающиеся с нуля...

Comment: @Harry Можете, пожалуйста, написать код? Я очень сильно тороплюсь

Comment: Знаете, я написал. Но увидел ваше "я тороплюсь" - и свой ответ удалил. Открою, если не забуду, завтра. Не люблю нахальных "шаровиков"...

Comment: [Наверное это не наивность, наверное это наглость](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11519/281034).

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Вот-вот. Но получилось даже удачно - открытым ответ провисел секунд 30, не больше. А не выступи он со своим "а ну-ка бегом!" - так бы и проскочил...

Comment: @Harry Я не имел ввиду чтобы вы срочно мне написали ответ, вы бы могли вообще ничего не писать... Извиняюсь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно то же самое. Выводите `0`, и далее рекурсивно для длины `n-1`, начинающиеся и с 0, и с 1. Потом - `1` и далее рекурсивно для `n-1`, начинающиеся с нуля...

Примерно так:

```
void out(int n, string prefix = "")
{
    char last = prefix.size() ? prefix[prefix.size()-1] : 0;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        if (last != '1') cout << prefix << '1' << endl;
        cout << prefix << '0' << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (last != '1')
        out(n-1,prefix+"1");
    out(n-1,prefix+"0");
}
```

См. рабочую программу - https://ideone.com/iOCXGe

Answer (score 2):

Не смог удержаться от соблазна решить задачу строя список из узлов на стеке. Программа печатает последовательности в необычном порядке, но про порядок в условии не сказано :):

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror print_fib_bins.cpp

#include <cstdio>

struct Node {
    char bit;
    const Node *next;
};

void print(const Node *list) {
    for (const Node *n = list; n != nullptr; n = n->next) {
        std::putc(n->bit, stdout);
    }
    std::putc('\n', stdout);
}

void print(int n, const Node *suffix) {
    if (n == 0) {
        print(suffix);
        return;
    }
    const Node node = {'0', suffix};
    print(n - 1, &node);
    if (suffix == nullptr || suffix->bit == '0') {
        const Node node = {'1', suffix};
        print(n - 1, &node);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    print(n, nullptr);
}
```

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror print_fib_bins.cpp
> $ echo 5 | ./a.out 
> 00000
> 10000
> 01000
> 00100
> 10100
> 00010
> 10010
> 01010
> 00001
> 10001
> 01001
> 00101
> 10101
> $ echo 35 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 24157817
> ```